# My Java code with FileWriter doesnot work

Tags: java

The following code seems to be not working. I want to write to a file in a certain path but when I try to run this code, it does not write to the file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    new File("PATH").mkdir();
    File myfile = new File("PATH");
    try {
        String name = "This is my code";
        char[] c = name.toCharArray();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(myfile);
        int k = 0;
        while (k < c.length) {
            fw.write(c[k]);
            k++;    
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: "does not work" .. can you be a bit more specific on that part?

Comment: It seems that your file is a directory.

Comment: Why are you creating a directory at `PATH` and then trying to write it as a file?

Comment: And why do you convert your data to a char array first? FileWriter has a method to write a whole String?

Comment: I want to write to the file using loop so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using FileWriter to write file

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] inputs = new String[] {"input-1","input-2","input-3"};
        File outputFile = new File("output.txt");
        try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outputFile)){
            for(String input:inputs) {
                writer.write(input);
            }   
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Using BufferedWriter to write file line by line

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] input = new String[] {"input-1","input-2","input-3"};
        File outputFile = new File("output-buffer.txt");
        try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile))){
            for(String inputLine:input) {
                writer.write(inputLine);
                writer.newLine();
            }   
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

From java7 onwards you can use [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) to write

```java
String text = "Text to save to file";
Files.write(Paths.get("./fileName.txt"), text.getBytes());
```